# Using PHP excel lib or python excel lib in PHP 7?

Tags: php, python, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

I have been working with both PHPExcel and Spreadsheet for generating and reading excel files in PHP5 but recently I've switched to PHP 7 that makes many trouble as those excel libs deprecated. I've searched a lot and finally I've found [PHPOffice](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet). What if I use Python excel library instead? Will it results better performance compare to using PHP lib?

Comment: you can use openpyxl: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-openpyxl and as they say: All kudos to the PHPExcel team as openpyxl was initially based on PHPExcel.

Comment: I've already known the library and I've been using this in my application to convert CSV file to excel. thanks anyway.